# Prove double negation of LEM in intuitionistic logic

Tags: logic, intuitionistic-logic

I understand that in intuitionistic logic, the law of excluded middle $P \lor \lnot P$ and double negation elimination $\lnot \lnot P \to P$ are ***not*** true in general (for every proposition $P$). However, I understand that $\lnot \lnot (P \lor \lnot P)$ and $P \to \lnot \lnot P$ ***are*** intuitionistically true in general. Is there an "intuitive" intuitionistic proof for these?

Comment: So, you are asking *not* the formal proof of them, but rather, motivation for these facts?

Answer (score 3):

In general, see [Glivenko's result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-negation_translation#Propositional_logic).
Your statements we can prove by proving theorems in the positive fragment of intuitionistic logic with a propositional variable $C$ and then letting $C=\bot$.

- The double negation introduction, $A\to \neg\neg A$, is [modus ponens](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_ponens) in the form $$A\to ((A\to C)\to C)$$
- Similarly, $\neg\neg(A\lor\neg A)$ is the special case of $$\big[\big(A\lor(A\to C)\big)\to C\big]\to C$$
  To see why this holds, assume $\big(A\lor(A\to C)\big)\to C$ and note that it functions as a valid premise for itself: Just the left side of "$\lor$" says $A$ implies $C$, meaning we conclude $A\to C$. Now using this for the right side of "$\lor$" we conclude $C$.

It's worth pointing out that this goes through in logics weaker than intuitionistic logic. We **do not need** the [principle of explosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion) to show it. And indeed we don't even use a conjunction "$\land$", which I'll make use of in the motivation part.

---

Consider modus ponens in the curried form $(B\land (B\to C))\to C$. Again with $C=\bot$, we obtain the valid non-contradiction principle $\neg(B\land \neg B)$. Consider the more particular $\neg(\neg A\land \neg \neg A)$, saying that the proposition $B=\neg A$ cannot be witnessed and rejected at the same time. Three of the four [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws#In_intuitionistic_logic) are intuitionistically valid. If you're taking the latter for granted, the double-negated excluded middle $\neg\neg(A\land \neg A)$ is also proven after pulling the negation through the bracket. And in a consistent system, you may also read $A\to\neg\neg A$ as expressing that if $A$ has been established, then it cannot anymore be rejected.

---

For a pedestrian proof, note that the following holds:
$$\Big(\ \big((A\lor B)\to C\big)\ \ \land\ \ \big(((A\to C)\land (B\to C))\to D\big)\ \Big)\to D$$
To see its validity, note that expression $(A\lor B)\to C$ says that both $A$ and $B$ imply $C$, which is exactly what the second expression demands to prove $D$. The special case $B=A\to\bot$ and $C=D=\bot$ of this reads
$$\neg\big[\neg (A\lor \neg A) \land \neg((\neg A) \land \neg (\neg A)) \big]$$
We recognize the established the non-contradiction principle on the right and are thus left with $\neg\neg (A\lor \neg A)$.

**Note:** The user in the comments points out a variant of this proof that effectively uses one of De Morgan's laws and also again the noncontradiction principle.
This avoids the fourth propositional variable, $D$. It basically uses $(P\to\bot) = \neg P$ instead of $\neg(P\land \neg\bot) = \neg P$ that I used above.

Comment: (+1) Might be clearer to phrase as follows: $$ ((A\lor B)\to C)\leftrightarrow ((A\to C)\land (B\to C))$$ is clear for reasons similar to what you say. And then taking  $C=\bot$ and $B=\lnot A$ gives $\lnot(A\lor \lnot A)\leftrightarrow (\lnot A\land \lnot\lnot A),$ and then the result follows from $(\lnot A\land \lnot\lnot A)\leftrightarrow \bot.$

Answer (score 2):

For $P \to \lnot \lnot P$.

Note that negation introduction is "safe" also for [Intuitionistic Logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-intuitionistic/).

According to the [BHK interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brouwer%E2%80%93Heyting%E2%80%93Kolmogorov_interpretation) we have:

> There is no proof of $\bot$

> A proof of $P\to Q$ is a function that converts a proof of $P$ into a proof of $Q$.

Assume we have a proof of $P$ and assume that we have a proof of $P \to \bot$. By Modus Ponens, we get a proof of $\bot$, that is impossible.

Thus, starting from a proof of $P$, we can build a function that converts a proof of $P \to \bot$ into a proof of $\bot$, i.e. into a proof of $(P \to \bot) \to \bot$.

---

For $¬¬(P∨¬P)$, we have to observe that Intuitionistic rejection of LEM means that LEM is not valid, not that it is false.

In IL we prove that $¬(P∨¬P)$ leads to a contradiction, and this amounts to a prove of $¬¬(P∨¬P)$.

The proof uses negation introduction and disjunction introduction, and both principles are intuitionistically safe.

From an [Intuitionistic point of view (Brouwer, 1908)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/intuitionistic-logic-development/#BrouViewLogi19071908), LEM amounts to the (unreliable) principle that every mathematical problem is decidable, while $¬¬(P∨¬P)$ amounts to asserting the principle that no absolutely unsolvable problem exists (Heyting, 1934).

Answer (score 1):

here is an intuitive-ish intuitionistic proof of $¬¬(p \vee \neg p)$. Since $\neg x$ means $x \to \bot$, we need to show $\neg (p \vee \neg p) \vdash \bot$.  That means it's enough to show that $\neg (p \vee \neg p) \vdash \neg p$, since once we have $\neg p$ we can get $p \vee \neg p$ which together with $\neg (p \vee \neg p)$ gives $\bot$ as required.

To show $\neg(p\vee \neg p) \vdash \neg p$ it's enough to show $p, \neg(p\vee \neg p) \vdash \bot$. But that's easy: $p \vdash p \vee \neg p$, so $p, \neg (p \vee \neg p)\vdash p \vee \neg p$, and again recalling that $\neg x$ is $x \to \bot$ we get $p, (\neg(p\vee\neg p)) \vdash \bot$.